# how to insert values under same id but different column values?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I like to insert my data like following structure.

```
    +------+----+
    |id|JAN||FEB|
    +------+----+
    |1 |  1||  5|
    +------+----+
    |2 |  8|| 12|
    +------+----+
    |3 | 15|| 19|
    +------+----+
    |4 | 22|| 26|
    +------+----+


<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "epi";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) 
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$number_of_dates = 4;
$startDate_Jan = strtotime("2018-01-01");
for ($i = 0; $i <= $number_of_dates; $i++)
{
    $date = strtotime("Monday +" . ($i * 1) . ' weeks', $startDate_Jan);
    $month=date('m', $date).PHP_EOL;
    $datex=date('d', $date).PHP_EOL;
    $intmonth = intval($month);
    $intdate = intval($datex);

    echo $intdate;
    echo "<br>";

    $sql="INSERT INTO testdata (ID_DATE, EPI_DATE_JAN) VALUES ('','$intdate')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}

$number_of_dates = 4;
$startDate_Feb = strtotime("2018-02-01");
for ($i = 0; $i <= $number_of_dates; $i++)
{
    $date = strtotime("Monday +" . ($i * 1) . ' weeks', $startDate_Feb);
    $month=date('m', $date).PHP_EOL;
    $datex=date('d', $date).PHP_EOL;
    $intmonth = intval($month);
    $intdate = intval($datex);

    echo $intdate;
    echo "<br>";

    $sql="INSERT INTO testdata (ID_DATE, EPI_DATE_FEB) VALUES ('','$intdate')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

when I do like above then total 8 id is being created. So now I want to fix my problem. tell me some solution how can solve my problem. if you have still confusion then ask me, I will give some details also.

Comment: for the first 4  you need insert but for the others you need  update  ..

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only 4 rows in your table and the ID_DATE is the number of the week, you could use an UPDATE in your second loop as follow:

```
// second loop:
$week = $i+1;
$sql="UPDATE testdata set EPI_DATE_FEB = $intdate WHERE ID_DATE=$week";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

So the second loop could be:

```
$number_of_dates = 4;
$startDate_Feb = strtotime("2018-02-01");
for ($i = 0; $i <= $number_of_dates; $i++)
{
    $date = strtotime("Monday +" . ($i * 1) . ' weeks', $startDate_Feb);
    $month=date('m', $date).PHP_EOL;
    $datex=date('d', $date).PHP_EOL;
    $intmonth = intval($month);
    $intdate = intval($datex);

    echo $intdate;
    echo "<br>";

    $week = $i+1;
    $sql="UPDATE testdata SET EPI_DATE_FEB=$intdate WHERE ID_DATE=$week";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

But it's even better to use [prepared queries](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: yes this is possible. but this is only for two months. But I need it for 12 months and for others day and also some conditions there too which manage in same file will be difficult. Is there alternative way?

anyway thanks.

Comment: @Jubayer Ok. I see. Do you have only 4 rows in this table? Or could you add a column "week" (from 1 to 4)?

Comment: I have only 4 rows in this table.

Comment: @Jubayer Please see the last part of updated answer.

Comment: @Jubayer Updated again (`$week = $i+1`) to match

Comment: one more question, if I add another weekdays on the for loop like "Thursday" and count it for 8 days. 4 days for Monday and another 4 days for Thursday. What will be SQL query for that?

Comment: @Jubayer Hard to say in comments. But I think, something like this: `$week = ($i*2)+1;` + 1st update for Monday, then in the same loop, `$week = ($i*2)+2;` + 2nd update for Thursday.

Comment: thanks, that work for Jan & Feb. I am really feel uncomfortable to ask you another question. But I have to know it. If I add another month march; like Jan & Feb with the same conditions (for two days a week as my previous comment I mentioned) then what will be my sql query for that? I am really sorry to ask you again.

Comment: @Jubayer If you have another column (`EPI_DATE_MAR`) for that month, exactly the same. Not really sure to understand your issue for March. `UPDATE testdata SET EPI_DATE_MAR=$intdate WHERE ID_DATE=$week`.

Comment: but for march I don't get the actual value, for march in browser it prints, 5
1
12
8
19
15
27
22

but it db it shows,
5
0
8
0
15
0
22
0

Comment: @Jubayer I'm sorry, but it's really hard to say what's going wrong without the code under the eyes. Maybe try to ask another question with your new issue. I'll have a look if I can (soon bedtime for me). Thank you.

Comment: ok thank you so much. I will post it with new issue. It is also bedtime for me. Good night. :)